# How to make a loop in scraping a page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a page but I have a problem. I don't want to print items['Paragraphs'] = response.css('p::text').extract() in a function again and again. Instead I want to make a loop of it. I tried several times but failed. Here is the code..

```
def parse_about(self, response):
    # do your stuff on a page
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {'name1':'Headings','name2':'Paragraphs'}
    finder = {'find1':'h2::text , #mainContent h1::text','find2':'p::text'}
    for name in names.values():
        for find in finder.values():
            items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
            yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you describe, what output do you want to get?

As far as I understood your problem, you can apply `zip` to your dicts, it will merge your values and make iteration possible in more clear way. And better to yield item in the end of cycle.

```
def parse_about(self, response):
    # do your stuff on a page
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {'name1':'Headings','name2': 'Paragraphs'}
    finder = {'find1':'h2::text , #mainContent h1::text', 'find2': 'p::text'}
    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
    yield items
```

Or just why not to write proper dict from the very beginning?

```
def parse_about(self, response):
    # do your stuff on a page
    items = response.meta['items']
    dct = {
        'Headings': 'h2::text , #mainContent h1::text',
        'Paragraphs': 'p::text',
    }
    for name, find in dct.iteritems():
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
    yield items
```

Comment: Instead of writing ```items['Paragraphs'] = response.css('p::text').extract()``` and so on after items variable, I want to make a loop so that I could not print these lines again and again to scrape particular part of a page. Here I am printing heading and text of a Dmoz website first page.